# Producer Consumer synchronization Java weird behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Producer producer = new Producer("Producer ");
    Consumer[] consumers = new Consumer[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < consumers.length; i++) {
        consumers[i] = new Consumer(producer,"Consumer " + i);
    }
    producer.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < consumers.length; i++) {

        consumers[i].start();
    }
}
}



class Producer extends Thread{

public ArrayList<Integer> buffer;
public int bufferSize = 20;
int fillCount = 0;
int emptyCount = bufferSize;
Integer item;

public Producer(String name) {
    super(name);
    buffer = new ArrayList<>(bufferSize);
}
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Producing");
        item = new Integer(1000);
        downEmpty();
        addItemtoBuffer();
        increaseFill();

    }
}
private void addItemtoBuffer() {
    synchronized (buffer) {
        buffer.add(item);
        System.out.println("Produced " + getName() + fillCount + " " + emptyCount);
    }
}
private void downEmpty() {
    while(emptyCount <= 0) {
                    //Busy Waiting when buffer is full
        //System.out.println("EmptyCount " + emptyCount);
    }
    --emptyCount;

}
private void increaseFill() {
    ++fillCount;
}
}

class Consumer extends Thread{

private Producer producer;
private ArrayList<Integer> buffer;
public Consumer(Producer producer, String name) {
    super(name);
    this.producer = producer;
    buffer = producer.buffer;
}
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        downFill();
        consume();
        increaseEmpty();
    }
}
private void downFill() {

    while(producer.fillCount <= 0) {
                    //Busy Waiting when buffer is empty
        //System.out.println("fillCount" + producer.fillCount + " EmptyCount" + producer.emptyCount);
    }
    --producer.fillCount;

}
private void increaseEmpty() {
    ++producer.emptyCount;
}
private void consume() {
    synchronized (buffer) {
        buffer.remove(buffer.size()-1);
        System.out.println("Consumed");
    }


}
}
```

Here's my solution to the producer consumer problem. Currently it has only 1 producer and 1 consumer. My problem with it is when I run it the Producer produces until the buffer is full and goes into a busy waiting. The consumer consumes for a while but stops allowing the producer to completely fill the buffer. At this moment fillCount is 20.
I have no idea why the consumer won't consume. The only busy waiting it has if fillCount is less than or equal to 0. The other possibility is it's waiting for the synchronized block but since the producer is in it's busy wait the buffer has to be free.
But there's an ever bigger thing. If i were to uncomment the sysouts in the busy waits it works! albeit a bit weird.
I need help and I need to get it to work with any number of producers and consumers. My question is why is the consumer not consuming and possibly getting it to work with multiple consumers.

Comment: How are you ensuring that access to `emptyCount` and `fillCount` are thread safe?  Is there any reason for the changes in one thread to be visible to the other?  Have you tried using AtomicInteger instead?

Comment: I initially had emptyCount and fillCount is Integer objects and synchronized them but I went back on it. Will try AtomicIntegers

Comment: Remember to only synchronize on `final` references to objects.  synchronizing on a changing reference doesn't do what you think it might ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a field which the JIT can detect a thread is not changing, it can inline it.  This means that instead of maybe, one day seeing a value changed by another thread, it never sees a change by another thread.

You could make the fields volatile, and this would more or less work, but a better solution is to use AtomicInteger which has thread safe increment and decrement.

For more info. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/demonstrating-when-volatile-is-required.html

Comment: Thanks now it's more or less working. I've also gotten multiple producers and consumers to work but it's not working as smoothly as I would like. Like one process is doing 5+ actions on the buffer at one time. I guess this is something i can't control

Comment: Since your consumers (and producers) are busy waiting, your solution will work best when you have two free logical CPUs per Producer/Consumer. If you don't have that many CPUs, you should expect to get significant delays.  A more scalable solution is to use a BlockingQueue or an Executor.